# Proof for integration by substitution

Tags: proof-verification

I have a question about the proof for integration by substitution. It starts the following way:

Let $ \phi: [a, b] \rightarrow [c, d]$ be continuously differentiable and $f: [c, d] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous. Furthermore, let $F: [c, d] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be an antiderivative. Applying the chain rule gives

$(F \circ \phi)' = (f \circ \phi) \phi'.$

Since $F \circ \phi$ is an antiderivative of $(f \circ \phi) \phi'$, applying the fundamental theorem of calculus gives

$\int_a^b f(\phi(t))\phi'(t) dt = F(\phi(b)) - F(\phi(a)).$

Now, how does he conclude the last step? I don't see how he is applying the theorem actually.

Comment: maybe you are looking for the change of limits:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integration_by_Substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe writing it as a simpler looking function will help. Let $F(x)$ be an antideriviative of $f(x)$. Let $H(x) = F(\phi(x))$. Then

$$H'(x) = F'(\phi(x))\cdot \phi'(x) = f(\phi(x))\cdot \phi'(x)$$

So, $H(x) = F(\phi(x))$ is an antiderivative of $f(\phi(x))\cdot \phi'(x)$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\begin{align*}\int_a^b f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) dt &= H(b) - H(a) \\ &= F(\phi(b)) - F(\phi(a))\end{align*}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $F'(\phi(x)) * \phi'(x)$ in the beginning actually?

Comment: Remember $F'=f$ - edit: ah i see. ill fix

Comment: Thank you, that's clear then.

Comment: But in this why we need $\phi(x)$ to be continuously differentiable

Answer (score 2):

look:
$$
\int_a^b f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt=\int_a^b F(\phi(t))'dt=[F(\phi(t))]_a^b=F(\phi(b))-F(\phi(a)).
$$

Best regards.